# How can I add the value of an observation in a column with an observation from another column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, analytics

Hey guys so I have this issue 
Who can help me with code or an algorithm that will take  fd.loc[0, ‘value 4’]  and add it to fd.loc[1, ‘value 2] to give the output of fd.loc[1, ‘value 4’] basically i want every observation in value 4 to be the sum of its previous observation and the corresponding observation in value 2 (i hope explain my problem properly)

```
dict = {
'value 1' : [1,2,3],
'value 2' : [4,5,6]
}

fd = pd.DataFrame(dict)
fd['value 4'] = 10 + fd['value 2']
fd
```

Comment: What is `fd.loc[0, ‘value 4’]` to begin with? And why does your code calculate `value 4` in a way that does not match your explanation?

Comment: fd.loc[0, ‘value 4’] is the first observation in the newly created column value 4
i want the second observation in the value 4 column to be the sum of the first observation (fd.loc[0, ‘value 4’])  and the second observation (fd.loc[1, ‘value 2]) in the column value 2 and so on does it make more sense?

Comment: IIUC this can be helpful here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html

Comment: thanks I will look into it

Comment: Still not sure if I understood you correctly, but I gave it a shot. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `'value 4'`-column already exists and you want to transform those values as you describe, you can do it like this:

```
fd['value 4'] = fd['value 2'] + fd['value 4'].shift()
```

Then you will just have to reassign `fd.loc[0, ‘value 4’]`, which is now `NaN`, and maybe recast the whole column to integer, as it has been converted to float because of the missing value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what do you want to achieve, but here are some ways:

Add the sum of two columns to one column, row by row:

```
fd.loc[index]['value 4'] = fd.loc[index]['value 1'] + fd.loc[index]['value 2']
```

Add a column where the value in each row is the sum of two columns:

```
fd['value 4'] = fd['value 1'] + fd['value 2']
```

you could also use a lambda function with [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
fd['value 4'] = fd.apply(lambda row: row['value 1'] + row['value 2'], axis=1)
```

I hope this answers your question